# User restriction based on ip address using rabbitMq Server

Tags: rabbitmq

We want to restrict user based on ip address while user connecting the rabbitmq server connection

Comment: Normally, it is responsibility of server itself to restrict or allow access from specific IP addresses to the server. In case of Linux system, it can be done via iptables, in Windows use P Security Policy Managment feature.

Answer (score 0):

Use [the `rabbitmq-auth-backend-ip-range` plugin](https://github.com/gotthardp/rabbitmq-auth-backend-ip-range/).